# how to remove a [ ] symbol from Flutter Strings?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can I ask help about my Flutter project, sqflite offline database, which i want to convert String to list, but there some issue: the [ ] symbol still there on List data, the question is, how to remove [ ] symbol from string data?

From:

```
String data = '[data0, data1, data2]';
```

to:

```
String data = 'data0, data2, data2';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all `[` and `]` use [`.replaceAll`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html)

```dart
  final result = data.replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]", "");
```

Also you can use Regex